# Interpret pie chart of the CPU load using DDMS tool in Android

Tags: android, load, cpu, pie-chart, ddms

I have used the **DDMS** tool from the Android Juno to test my **CPU load** within and Android application. There is shown different pie charts depending if I enter an app, use some function within a specific app, exit etc. For each of these there is shown some numbers, as it follows: **number/system_server (user);** **number/system_server (kernel)** etc.

The numbers are within **the interval [0, several thousands].** They also seem to correspond to specific areas from the pie chart.

I am interested in the **signification of these numbers**. Are they **number of processes** or what do they represent?

Thank you, in advance!